# Snap to Object/Control feature

Tags: c#, wpf

i am doing an editor kind of project application in wpf in which i am allowing user to drag their controls (i have defined my own controls that allows user to customize their screens) to the Canvas window i.e I have toolbar and canvas area.i have placed controls in the toolbar and those controls can be dragged and dropped on the canvas.

i am done with dragging and dropping stuff and currently looking for the feature that allows me to snap one control from the boundaries of another control while placing a control to Canvas.

i.e. when i am placing 2nd control benith/after of the 1st one and if 2nd control is coming in same vertical/horizontal line in that case system should show floating visible line to properly place control in one line.

The feature i have seen in Visual Studio form desigining such as,

[image]

Please, advice me how to do this thing.

Thanks in advance,
Mandar.........

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the full answer, but I do know the snap lines and grab handles in VS make use of the [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753340.aspx)